# Python while loop, if then conditions not working properly

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am new to Python and attempting my first while loop.

The below code is meant to iterate over the defined formula as defined by the user in the number_of_moves variable.

When `i = 1`, it should execute one formula, however when `i > 1` it should execute another. So I defined an *if else statement* inside a formula.

Issue is that when `i > 1` it does not pick up the 2nd formula but continues to use the first defined formula, which is `(22695477 * x + 1) % 2 ** 31`.

Effectively, the *else statement* `x2` should equal to the output from the previous iteration `x1` and `x3` should equal the value from the output of `x2` ... and so on ... using this formula `(22695477 * x2 + 1) % 2 ** 31`.

```
print("Choose the type of game(1:Easy;2 Difficult)")
levelinput = int(input())

print("")


print("Enter the number of moves")

number_of_moves = int(input())
i =1
x = 79
randomvalue = (22695477*x+1)%2**31
x2 = randomvalue
machine = int()


while i <= number_of_moves:
    print("")
    print("Choose your move number", i ,"(0 or 1)")

    move_selection = int(input())

    if i  == 1:
        randomvalue = (22695477*x+1)%2**31

    else:
        randomvalue = (22695477*x2+1)%2**31

    i = i +1


    if randomvalue <= 2**31:
        machine == int(0)
    else:
        machine == int(1)

    def resultgame (move_selection,machine):
        if move_selection == machine:
            return("Computer Wins")
        else:
            return("Player Wins")

    result = resultgame

    print("player = ", move_selection, "machine = ", machine,"-", result(move_selection,machine))
```

Comment: You never change `i`, so the while loop will loop forever, and the second function will always pick the 0 option. Is `if i == 1:` supposed to be `if move_selection == 1`?

Comment: no move selection is a binary category, either 1 or 0 - irrelevant to the question so deleted off here..thx

Comment: Be careful with your indentation. The code you show will not run.

Comment: `line 19: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Comment: @Probit Again, you never change `i` anywhere. It will always be 0. Please show the actual code you're running because this code will get stuck in the loop, and you never call LinearCong.

Comment: Code runs fine..in that it iterate i+=1, but for wtv reason is defaulting to the if statement formula and not the else formula

Comment: The code does not "run fine"; it doesn't even compile.

Comment: @Probit The code you posted here doesn't run fine though. Please show an [mcve] so we can tell what the actual problem is.

Comment: added the part that iterates to the code, i+=1

Comment: Hey you return the randomvalue so i+=1 is unreachable.

Comment: @Probit But your indentation is still off, so we can't tell when the increment is being run. And the increment is happening outside of the loop, so the while loop will still loop forever, and you never call the function. There's too much wrong with the code you posted for us to be able to tell whats causing the problem you're asking about.

Comment: Kindly use print(randomvalue) instead return randomvalue then  your loop will iterate properly.

Comment: @imsaiful A better fix would be to increment before the return, if that is the problem. We shouldn't be encouraging people to print instead of return. There's already enough confusion between the two.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks for pointing out. My intention was only by return statement his code is unreachable i.e. will never increment the value of i.

Comment: @imsaiful Why do you think that? The increment is not part of the function.

Comment: Now the code is fine. Apparently, it seems in the function body after return.

Comment: @melpomene First you reject my edits (which was approved by OP!) and then you make it as unreadable as it was before. Not helpful.

Comment: @Probit, if you're unsatisfied with the last edit from melpomene, you can just rollback his last edit. Otherwise feel free to let it as it is or edit it again.

Comment: @colidyre The problem was not the readability but the change in indentation, which makes the code behave differently. The code OP posted was broken (indentation error). Your edit changed the indentation in a certain way, but it's not clear why you chose that way. In any case, neither the original code nor your attempt at fixing it match OP's description, so the real code is something else anyway. Anyway, I don't like edits that try to "fix" code based on guesswork.

Comment: @melpomene - yes. That's right. But it was approved by OP. That's my point. Changing code is indeed a very problematic topic itself, see also this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325968/is-it-ok-to-edit-python-questions-to-make-them-pep-8-compliant/325970#comment613502_325970 -- but it's not worth debating this here.

Comment: @colidyre I didn't know it was approved by OP (before you mentioned it in your comment). I also assume OP doesn't know what they're doing because neither version of the code demonstrates anything like what OP is describing because `LinearCong` is never called. (What is OP even doing, approving random edits to the code instead of posting a [mcve] like they were asked to half an hour ago?)

Comment: @melpomene That's a point, too. The newest answer shows it. It's an answer with a lot of guessing what OP could mean. That's bad.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the code you have written, in the nicest possible way, is not good.

```
def LinearCong (x,x2):
  if i == 1:
    randomvalue = (22695477*x+1)%2**31
  else:
    randomvalue = (22695477*x2+1)%2**31

  return randomvalue

 x2 = randomvalue
 i+=1
```

This function should not be placed into a while loop, or any loop for that matter. For now I would advise to forget about using functions i.e `def function():`
While the syntax of what you have written is somewhat correct, It is not implemented correctly in the slightest bit.

Here is my interpretation of what you were trying to do in a simpler form.

```
i =1
number_of_moves = 10
x = 10000

#problem understanding
#included a randomvalue variable here becaause you want it to be assigned to var x2
#unless randomvalue is declared here the else statement would never work
randomvalue = (22695477*x+1)%2**31
x2 = randomvalue

while i <= number_of_moves:
    print("")
    print("Choose your move number", i ,"(0 or 1)")
    move_selection = int(input())

    if move_selection == 1:
        randomvalue = (22695477*x+1)%2**31
        break
    else:
        #here you are asking for var x2 which would have no value unless declared above
        #randomvalue as a variable is created here so x2 would have nothing to refer to
        randomvalue = (22695477*x2+1)%2**31
        #in this case, we are reassigning our already declared variable
        break

print(randomvalue)
```

There are big problems with this code I've written, but I don't fully understand what it is you are trying to achieve. Maybe more information about the game would help.

Comment: Why answering this question at all if it's so unclear?

Comment: @colidyre because this might help him figure out what he's doing

Comment: @Nick Eu, thanks Nick for your help, but x2 is still not being picked up as it should in the else statement. I've modified the code above taking into consideration some of your suggestions. Yet too no avail..